# Get XML column from XML in SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server

I need to get table with `Address` XML column from XML.

Here is what I do:

```
DECLARE @Person xml='<Person PersonID="a1fee068-aad4-459b-8ea7-063975f17bed">
  <Address State="1" District="15" House="test" Additional="1" />
  <Address State="8" District="11" Region="12" Neighborhood="13" Block="14" House="75" Additional="somewhere" />
</Person>'

DECLARE @handle INT  
DECLARE @PrepareXmlStatus INT  
EXEC @PrepareXmlStatus= sp_xml_preparedocument @handle OUTPUT, @Person  

SELECT  *
FROM  
OPENXML(@handle, '/Person', 2)  
WITH (
    Address xml
)  
EXEC sp_xml_removedocument @handle
```

The result is only first `Address` from the XML. I can't understand why....

Any suggestions how get all records with `Address` tag?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use a XML query like this:

> ```
> DECLARE @Person xml='
> <Person PersonID="a1fee068-aad4-459b-8ea7-063975f17bed">
>   <Address State="1" District="15" House="test" Additional="1" />
>   <Address State="8" District="11" Region="12" Neighborhood="13" Block="14" House="75" Additional="somewhere" />
> </Person>'
>
> SELECT data.value('./@State', 'int') as State,
>        data.value('./@District', 'int') as District,
>        data.value('./@House', 'nvarchar(50)') as House,
>        data.value('./@Additional', 'nvarchar(50)') as Additional,
>        data.value('./@Region', 'int') as Region,
>        data.value('./@Neighborhood', 'int') as Neighborhood,
>        data.value('./@Block', 'int') as Block
> FROM   @Person.nodes('/Person/Address') AS t1(data);
> ```
>
> ```
> State | District | House | Additional | Region | Neighborhood | Block
> ----: | -------: | :---- | :--------- | -----: | -----------: | ----:
>     1 |       15 | test  | 1          |   null |         null |  null
>     8 |       11 | 75    | somewhere  |     12 |           13 |    14
> ```

If you want each Address block:

> ```
>     SELECT data.query('.')
>     FROM   @Person.nodes('/Person/Address') AS t1(data)
>     GO
>
> | (No column name)                                                                                               |
> | :------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------- |
> | <Address State="1" District="15" House="test" Additional="1" />                                                |
> | <Address State="8" District="11" Region="12" Neighborhood="13" Block="14" House="75" Additional="somewhere" /> |
> ```

*dbfiddle [here](http://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2016&fiddle=ff60234325974e3cb75154b1963075fb)*

Comment: Get table then make XML FROM table?

Comment: What do you mean?

Comment: I need in result table with XML Column. So preferred result will be: row1='<Address State="1" District="15" House="test" Additional="1" />'; row2='<Address State="8" District="11" Region="12" Neighborhood="13" Block="14" House="75" Additional="somewhere" />'

Comment: To do that, simply add `FOR XML AUTO` before the `GO` (or specify explicit elements as needed)

Comment: Yep but I'll get xml with 2 elements, and not a table with 2 rows. Load my example in dbfiddle you'll see what i need. But there is only first row...

Comment: @ArkadiyV. is this the desired result?

Comment: Awesome! Thanks a lot!

Comment: I'm glad to help